# How to print Data-table with div content

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Unable to print datatable with border and div content.
I already tried datatable print plugins but it can only print datatable..

**HTML :**

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 panel panel-default" id="testreportTable">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnPrint">Print</button>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center" >
            <h4>Stack OverFlow Test</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <h5><b>Test Page</b></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" id="TestReportTable">
                 <thead>
                      <tr>
                         <th>Name</th>
                         <th>Location</th>
                         <th>Duration</th>
                         <th>Remarks</th>
                      </tr>
                </thead>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var data = [
{name:"Fiat", location:"Mumbai", duration:"2 Hours",remarks:"Ready"},         {name:"Tata", location:"Mumbai", duration:"3 Hours",remarks:"Ready"}
                ];

 var ops_table = $('#TestReportTable').dataTable(
             {
                 "bPaginate": false,
                 "bLengthChange": false,
                 "bFilter":true,
                 "bInfo" : false,
                 "oLanguage": {
                       "sSearch": ""
                   },
                 "aoColumns":[{"bSearchable": true},{"bSearchable":true},{"bSearchable":true},{"bSearchable":true}]
             });

     var dataArray = [];
     $.each(data,function(i,dataFirst)
{dataArray.push([dataFirst.name,dataFirst.location,dataFirst.duration,dataFirst.remarks]);
     })

      ops_table.fnClearTable();
        ops_table.fnAddData(dataArray);

    function getPrint(){
        var divToPrint=$('#testreportTable');
        var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
        newWin.document.open();
        newWin.$(document.body).append('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
        newWin.document.close();
        setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
    }


    $('#btnPrint').on('click',function(){
        getPrint()
    })
```

please refer this fiddle..

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raskarvishal7/Lk6n8pyw/1/)

please suggest..

Thnks..

Comment: "_Can you give me any lights on how to do this?_", perhaps - if You can tell us what you are trying to do.  What does "_print Data-table with div content_" mean?  How is the `document.write()` snippets related to the question, besides we can see you (perhaps) are including some dataTables plugins?

Comment: this multiple plugins added in one js file.. thats why i write this code in `document.write()`

Comment: Yes, but including the plugin files is a basic prerequisite; you would never ask a jQuery question and only tell that you have included jQuery, but leave the interesting and relevant code out, would you? :) I do not intend to be harsh, just want to increase your chances for a qualified answer. Without being precise on exactly what you are trying to do, I fear your question will end up unanswered.  And even if it was answered it would be useless for future readers, answers to unspecified problems people not can recognise does not get much attention.

Comment: Please Suggest.. @davidkonrad

Answer (score 0):

HTML:-

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 panel panel-default" id="testreportTable">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnPrint">Print</button>
<div id="corporateInfoId">        
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-center" >
            <h4>Stack OverFlow Test</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <h5><b>Test Page</b></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" id="TestReportTable">
                 <thead>
                      <tr>
                         <th>Name</th>
                         <th>Location</th>
                         <th>Duration</th>
                         <th>Remarks</th>
                      </tr>
                </thead>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:-

```
var data = [
    {name:"Fiat", location:"Mumbai", duration:"2 Hours",remarks:"Ready"},         {name:"Tata", location:"Mumbai", duration:"3 Hours",remarks:"Ready"}
                    ];

     var ops_table = $('#TestReportTable').dataTable(
                 {
                     "bPaginate": false,
                     "bLengthChange": false,
                     "bFilter":true,
                     "bInfo" : false,
                     "oLanguage": {
                           "sSearch": ""
                       },
                     "aoColumns":[{"bSearchable": true},{"bSearchable":true},{"bSearchable":true},{"bSearchable":true}]
                 });

         var dataArray = [];
         $.each(data,function(i,dataFirst)
    {dataArray.push([dataFirst.name,dataFirst.location,dataFirst.duration,dataFirst.remarks]);
         })

          ops_table.fnClearTable();
            ops_table.fnAddData(dataArray);

        function getPrint(){
            var divToPrint=$('#testreportTable');
var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
    'table th, table td {' +
    'border:1px solid #000;' +
    'padding;0.5em;' +
    '}' +
    '.pagination{' +
    'display:none;' +
    '}' +
    '.dataTables_filter{' +
    'display:none;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';
    var oSettings = ops_table.fnSettings();
    oSettings._iDisplayLength = -1;
    ops_table.fnDraw();
            var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
            newWin.document.open();
            newWin.$(document.body).append('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+htmlToPrint+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
oSettings._iDisplayLength = 10;
    ops_table.fnDraw();
            newWin.document.close();
            setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
        }


        $('#btnPrint').on('click',function(){
            getPrint()
        })
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/Lk6n8pyw/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Try append method in jquery

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    $("div").append("<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>");


<body>

<div></div>

</body>
```

Comment: May I ask : Why do you think he should try that ...?